# How to get the color burst wallpaper frames

Tags: macbook-pro, wallpaper

In the [Apple commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BkskUE8_hA), it shows the color burst wallpaper having different frames. Is there a way to achieve this effect on a Mac (MacBook Air) without a Touch Bar? Can I get the other frames downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pictures in that advertisement do not come preinstalled on the MacBook Pro with (or without) the Touch Bar and do not seem to be provided by Apple separately. It appears that those images were used solely for advertising purposes and are not available. There are three similar "color burst" images with combined colors (See pictures).

**Note:** The photo quality have been degraded by 70% to allow for them to be uploaded.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you would like to get the Photos you can make a feature request at https://www.apple.com/feedback/.

Comment: So......how does one obtain the images (what the OP asked)?

Comment: The OP also asked is it possible. Which, from my answer, I have explained that it is not possible to get these pictures. Additionally, I have provided a similar solution and attached images of similar backgrounds that do come preinstalled.

Comment: The images I have provided are also in the advertisement.

Comment: "don't come preinstalled" != "it's not possible."

Comment: You are correct. I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: You may want to check out this link.... http://osxdaily.com/2016/11/29/6-new-wallpapers-from-macos-sierra-10-12-2-and-ios-10-2/  or this one:  https://imgur.com/a/E84m9.  Both have the high quality images (second one has 5K images)

Comment: @Allan I would suggest commenting that on the actual question.  The link you have provided is helpful but the other color splashes (the ones included on that link but are not in my answer) I do not think are very similar to what the OP requested (and therefore did not include in my answer), but the OP may think differently.